# How to send a confirmation email with Sendgrid and Strapi every time I register a new "student" entity?

Tags: javascript, email, nuxt.js, sendgrid, strapi

I’ve managed to integrate Sengrid with Strapi. Got as far as sending emails with Postman.

Now, in my case, I’d like to extend that functionality, maybe with a hook, to send a confirmation email to the student’s email address every time I register a new student.

Could this be done straight from the strapi dashboard when creating a new student or from the Nuxt frontend?

Comment: Sending mails is more of a backend task. So, do it on Strapi if you can, if you can't, maybe look to have a simple backend to handle that work.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731047/strapi-how-to-send-confirmation-email-when-user-signup)

Comment: @RahulSingh will do. thank you!