# Strapi new user registration keeps getting "Email is already taken" error, no email confirmation either

Tags: registration, strapi, email-confirmation

I initialized a new Strapi server and with different databases and when registering a new user I keep getting the same  "message": "Email is already taken" error.  I used a different username and different email each time.  I also couldn't get the email confirmation to work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this exact issue, here is how I solved it.  You have to insure that you give Strapi native email plugin a VALID email address.

1. In the admin panel goto Settings -> Advanced Settings -> turn on Email Confirmation and hit Save.

[image]

2. Under settings -> Email Templates -> for both Email Address Confirmation and Reset Password provide a valid email, make sure that it's a working and valid email. If not you will keep getting that error.
   [image]

Strapi has a built in email plugin that manages emails.  You can also use a bunch of 3rd party email services to better manage your email.
[Optional Strapi Email Plugins](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/email.html#programmatic-usage)

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, that fixed my issues!!

Comment: not working on my case

Comment: that saved my life lol, it worked here thanks!

Comment: After I turn that on, newly registered users are forced to confirm their emails. But I don't really want that... In my app, unconfirmed users can continue using the app. Is there a way to adjust this? Or is there a way to send email confirmation programmatically (if yes, I can turn the setting off and send an email with the code)? Thanks