# Strapi email confirmation is not working properly. I click the link and nothing happens

Tags: email, strapi, password-confirmation

I'm having issues understanding how the Strapi email confirmation is supposed to work. I get this:
http://0.0.0.0/auth/emailconfirmation?confirmation=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

eStrapi has a built in email plugin that handles that, you can also add third party email providers.
The way it works is that Strapi sends a email with a link that has a hash attached to it.  When you click it, it will go to SERVER host with a specific endpoint in the URL and the server will automatically validate your email.  There are some steps to have to follow:

1. under your Admin panel go to: settings -> User Permissions Plugin -> email templates enter a VALID shipper and response email for all templates.
2. Under User Permissions Plugin -> Advanced Settings -> Enable Email Confirmation and add a redirect URL for after it is confirmed. ex. https://your-site.com/login
3. Under User Permissions Plugin -> Roles -> -> Public -> User Permissions -> Auth -> sendEmailConfirmation  checked.
4. Create this folder structure under config --> env --> production -> server.js and paste this in the file:

```js
  module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    host: env('HOST'),
    port: env.int('PORT'),
    url: env('BACKEND_URL'),
});
```

6. Then inside your code under config -> server.js insure that you add a url key.

```js
  module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
          host: env('HOST'),
          port: env.int('PORT'),
          url: env('BACKEND_URL_LOCAL'),
        });
```

inside your .env variables add your server url's for hosted and local, Make sure you set your NODE_ENV for the proper environments:

```
    BACKEND_URL=https://my-app.herokuapp.com
    BACKEND_URL_LOCAL=http://localhost:1337
    # NODE_ENV=production
    NODE_ENV=development
```

test both your served backend as well as the local.  Your full url string should look something like this:

local ->  http://localhost:1337/api/auth/email-confirmation?confirmation=6d3a77679db63a94c16307ae133d9373b23c3986

hosted -> https://my-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth/email-confirmation?confirmation=738a515de684eb58dfb5e4aaa7fe7a9f35aa32454

insure that the /api is in both links.

Comment: Hi does the link to confirm email suppose to work out of the box without anymore extra programming?  I got my link MY_IP_ADDRESS:1337/api/auth/email-confirmation?confirmation=33c73ae3d609a7d23e32180aea643b03ce78f273 to be sent to the email but when I go to the link by pasting it to the browser I get nothing and the email does not get confirmed....

Comment: so it seems like MY_IP_ADDRESS:1337/api/auth/email-confirmation endpoint is not setup properly.....

Comment: thankyou for the explanation! you beat the docs hands down ha ha. The part thats confusing is that the email link hits a backend endpoint, then redirects the confirmed user to the front

Comment: Ummm ... question, how does the frontend page then access the user's id so they can be logged in and their details pulled?

Comment: Hi @preston what was the fix for the endpoint? I also have the same issue. 

address:1337/api/auth/email-confirmation?confirmation=33c73ae3d609a7d23e32180aea643b03ce78f273